# How can I specify the bitmap format (e.g. RGBA_8888) with BitmapFactory.decode*()?

Tags: android, bitmapfactory

I'm making several calls to `BitmapFactory.decodeFile()` and `BitmapFactory.decodeResource()`, and I'd like to specify the format the bitmaps are decoded to, such as RGB_565 or RGBA_8888.

Currently, the decoded bitmap format seems to depend on the incoming image. Alternatively, is there a way to convert an existing bitmap to a specific format?

The reason this is important is that when I try to decode the image using `jnigraphics`, some images return an `AndroidBitmapFormat` of type `ANDROID_BITMAP_FORMAT_NONE`, which I assume is useless. Does anyone have more insight into why the format would be none of the known values? When this happens, the built-in image picker correctly displays images that are decoded this way, so I assume there has to be a way to deal with them.

Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This might be what you are looking for:

```
BitmapFactory.Options op = new BitmapFactory.Options();
op.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, op);
```

Comment: RGBA8888 not ARGB

Answer (score 1):

When you have bitmap you can call copy method on it specifying BitmapConfig which is basically what you want.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#copy(android.graphics.Bitmap.Config,boolean)

Comment: I was hoping there would be a way to do this during decode, instead of making a copy later. It looks like this is the only way though.