# Color depth in Android

Tags: android, color-depth

I just displayed a bitmap on a samsung galaxy 10.2. The image was created in photoshop showing some subtle change from a light red to a slightly darker red, it looked perfect on my PC, but the rendering on the tablet showed [multiple bands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colour_banding).

I know this can be caused by insufficient colour depth... but I don't know what colour depth android devices have. Does android even specify a minimum colour depth? Is the colour depth something you can request more or less of at runtime? Is it just up to the manufacturer of the device?

[image]

Comment: We need more context. Are you doing this in an Activity? If so, try `getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);`.

Comment: Yes, in an activity. So I assume RGBA_8888 is 32bits per pixel... but are all Android devices guaranteed to support this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a perfect reading: [Bitmap quality, banding and dithering](http://www.curious-creature.org/2010/12/08/bitmap-quality-banding-and-dithering/) by Romain Guy.

Answering your questions:

> Does android even specify a minimum colour depth?

Android < 2.3 loads bitmaps with 16 bits color depth by default. Android >= 2.3 loads bitmaps with 32 bits by default. Quoting Romain Guy from the given article:

> A much better solution is simply to render 32 bits bitmaps on 32 bits
>   surfaces, which Android 2.3 now does by default.

The minimum for bitmaps is 8 bits, [`Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html), but on 99% you shouldn't use this, but rather [`Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html#ARGB_8888).

Set your [`Window`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html) to 32 bits (`Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888`) and decode your bitmaps with 32 bits ([`PixelFormat.RGBA_8888`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PixelFormat.html#RGBA_8888)). How to do it, below.

> Is the colour depth something you can request more or less of at
>   runtime? Is it just up to the manufacturer of the device?

You can set color depth of a `Window` or a `Bitmap` at anytime during the runtime.

- For the `Window` with [`setFormat()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setFormat%28int%29) and [`PixelFormat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PixelFormat.html).
- [For the `Bitmap`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480182/how-can-i-specify-the-bitmap-format-e-g-rgba-8888-with-bitmapfactory-decode) with [`PixelFormat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PixelFormat.html).