# How to set bitmap to ARGB_8888 in android?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, alpha

In my android project, I load a bitmap from a image in the phone. I then do various image manipulations to it like cropping, resizing, editing pixel values.

But the problem is the format of the bitmap is not ARGB_8888, so its not really storing the alpha values. Or rather its always keeping them at 255.

How can I load the bitmap in ARGB_8888 format? This is my code to load and resize.
How can I specify the format in any of these?

Thanks

```
private static Bitmap resize(Bitmap img, int newW, int newH) throws IOException {
    Bitmap resizedImg = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(img, newW, newH, false);
    img.recycle();

    Bitmap newresizedImg = resizedImg.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    resizedImg.recycle();


    Pixel initialPixel = Function.getPixel(0, 0, newresizedImg, null);
    int a = initialPixel.getColor().getAlpha(); // -> 255
    newresizedImg.setPixel(0, 0, Pixel.getTransparentColor().getRGB());
    initialPixel = Function.getPixel(0, 0, newresizedImg, null);
    int new_a = initialPixel.getColor().getAlpha(); // -> 255

    return newresizedImg;
}

private static Bitmap getImage(String from) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(from);

    if (file.exists()) {
        BitmapFactory.Options op = new BitmapFactory.Options(); 
        op.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888; 
        Bitmap bufferedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(from, op);
        return bufferedImage;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Pixel class

```
public static Color getTransparentColor() {
    return new Color(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Color class

```
public int getRGB() {
    return ((A << 24) | 0xFF) + ((R << 16) | 0xFF) + ((G << 8) | 0xFF) + (B | 0xFF);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can copy your bitmap using this type of function (or you know, not use a function depending on how you want to use it)

```
private Bitmap ARGBBitmap(Bitmap img) {
  return img.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888,true);
}
```

Comment: What file format you reading into it? I've used code very similar to yours above with great success. What file format? Can you perhaps provide a sample of the image you're having issues with? Have you stepped through the function with a debugger to check all the getPixel functions to make sure they're returning the results you expect?

Answer (score 1):

`BitmapFactory.Options op = new BitmapFactory.Options();
op.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, op);`

from: [How can I specify the bitmap format (e.g. RGBA_8888) with BitmapFactory.decode*()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480182/how-can-i-specify-the-bitmap-format-e-g-rgba-8888-with-bitmapfactory-decode)

Comment: I think I lose the Alpha support when I resize it. How can I fix it?

Comment: It shouldn't lose Alpha 'support' what's the code you used for resizing?

Comment: Umm stupid me. Well you are creating a new Bitmap which hasn't got that setting yet.

Comment: How can I specify that setting when I resize it?

Comment: Isn't there a fourth parameter for a `Bitmap.Config...` when creating the resized image?

Comment: resizing already takes 4 parameters, if you mean fifth, then I tried it and it doesn't support that.

Comment: I put code above that gets the alpha from the first pixel, and its 255, then I set it to 0 alpha, and when I get the alpha again, its back to 255. This is after I did the copy command with the alpha support setting.

Comment: Bitmap convertedBitmap = convert(bitmap, Bitmap.Config.RGB_8888); hmm found this somewhere

Comment: What class has the convert function?

Comment: whoops forgot the link :(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15058905/converting-bitmap-in-memory-to-bitmap-with-bitmap-config-rgb-565

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps as this works for me.

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(marker.getMeasuredWidth(), marker.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
public Bitmap highlightImage(Bitmap src) { 
    Bitmap bmOut = Bitmap.createBitmap(src.getWidth() + 96, src.getHeight() + 96, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); 
    return bmOut;
}
```

Comment: Why the +96 height and width?

Comment: Not necessary to use +96. I have use that to scale the image.It's necessity purpose.

Comment: Oh it's an example my bad